# How can I loop through arrays inside an object in JavaScript es6?

Tags: javascript

How can I loop through arrays inside an object in JavaScript es6? I tried the following code

```
for(let x of Object.keys(headings?.value)){
              console.log(x);
            }
```

data i wants to loop through

```
"value":{
        "h3":[
           "Best selling products",
           "Best Corporate Laptops",
           "BEST PRICED LAPTOPS",
           "Shop By Brands"
        ],
        "h4":[
           "Lenovo Thinkpad Touchscreen Yoga X380\/i5\/8th gen\/13.3\" screen",
           "Lenovo thinkpad T440S\/core i7\/4th gen\/14\"screen"
        ],
        "h5":[
           "View All",
           
        ]
     }
```

Comment: Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)[`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) instead of `Object.keys()`. Also, you don't need `?.`; just use `headings.value`. If `headings` is nullish `Object.keys()`/`.values()` will throw an error anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate through object values - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547252/iterate-through-object-values-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you know each key, you just need to access the values of the object.

Alternatively, you can use `Object.values()` if you don't care about the keys

```js
const headings = {
  "value":{
      "h3":[
         "Best selling products",
         "Best Corporate Laptops",
         "BEST PRICED LAPTOPS",
         "Shop By Brands"
      ],
      "h4":[
         "Lenovo Thinkpad Touchscreen Yoga X380\/i5\/8th gen\/13.3\" screen",
         "Lenovo thinkpad T440S\/core i7\/4th gen\/14\"screen"
      ],
      "h5":[
         "View All",

      ]
   }
 };

console.log("KEY/VALUE PAIRS");
for(let key of Object.keys(headings.value)){
  const val = headings.value[key];
  console.log(key, val);
}

console.log("VALUES ONLY");
for(let val of Object.values(headings.value)){
  console.log(val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript ES6, you can use the Object.entries() method to get both the keys and values of the object. Then, you can iterate through each array using a nested loop. Here's how you can do it:

```js
const headings = {
  "value": {
    "h3": [
      "Best selling products",
      "Best Corporate Laptops",
      "BEST PRICED LAPTOPS",
      "Shop By Brands"
    ],
    "h4": [
      "Lenovo Thinkpad Touchscreen Yoga X380\/i5\/8th gen\/13.3\" screen",
      "Lenovo thinkpad T440S\/core i7\/4th gen\/14\"screen"
    ],
    "h5": [
      "View All",
    ]
  }
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(headings?.value)) {
  console.log(`Heading level: ${key}`);
  for (const item of value) {
    console.log(item);
  }
}
```